# Can you use Major Creation to create the diamond dust required for Resurrection?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spell-components

I have a character who is able to cast [*major creation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/major-creation) and [*resurrection*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resurrection). He has a CL of 15.

He starts by taking a really small piece of diamond (not enough to cast Resurrection), and casts *major creation* to make 15 cubic feet of diamond. I estimate that this diamond would be worth more than 10,000gp.
This diamond will last 150 minutes, which is more than is necessary to pulverize it into diamond powder and cast *resurrection*, using the created dust as component.

Is there something in this process that shouldn't work?

I am asking for RAW. I know this could be easily patched, which is what I expect my GM to do, but am curious about the rules.

Comment: 15 cubic feet of diamond is about 2.1 million carat, or 424,75 kilograms. That's quite the stone!

Comment: I removed your edit since it was asking a similar, but different question. You should therefore [ask a new question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can access your old edit through the revision history, by clicking on ["edited X ago"](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/82386/revisions), if you want to copy the wording.

Comment: Is 150 minutes really long enough to pulverize 15 cubic feet of diamond?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Psssh. I've seen bigger. http://www.space.com/26335-coldest-white-dwarf-star-diamond.html

Comment: Note that the spell that *does* work for this is *Fabricate*.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**No**, [Major Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/major-creation) works like [Minor Creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/minor-creation), which states:

> Attempting to use any created object as a **material component** causes the spell to **fail**.

You can create your diamond dust, but that dust cannot be used as material component for spells.
You could probably attempt to sell it, make some money, and then use it to buy non-magical diamond dust. But be careful to not get caught.

Comment: Set up a diamond dust laundering service. "I'll give you 15,000gp worth of dust in exchange for your 10,000gp worth of dust..."

Comment: How can you tell the magical from the mundane diamond dust? Dispel Magic?

Comment: Detect magic should be enough. If they are all mixed together, then you probably need Dispel Magic.

Comment: Magic aura manipulation spells do exist and should be used prior to any fraud attempt to prevent immediate detection by any non-idiot merchants.